# Puzzled about php navigation

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to turn this link into a php foreach loop  without success and new to Stack overflow. I have used an array to generate the code but unsure how to turn this code into a foreach loop

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-first">
   <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am just wondering how to create the li code for the foreach loop

```
foreach ($navItems as $item) {
   echo "<li><a href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post the code you had a question about?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
"Home" => array("link" => "#home", "title" => "Take me home!"),
"About" => array("link" => "#about", "title" => "Learn more about us")
);
?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-first">
<? php
foreach ($array as $navTitle => $data) {?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $data['link']?>" class="smoothScroll" title="<?php echo $data['title']?>"><?php echo $navTitle?></a>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Dazza210169 -  Would you mind accepting it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
  echo "<li><a href='".$item['slug']."' class='smoothScroll'>".$item['title']."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $items = array( 'About' => 'about' );  ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-first">
   <?php foreach ( $items as $i_name => $i_ref ): ?>
   <li><a href="#<?= $i_ref ?>" class="smoothScroll"><?= $i_name ?></a></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```